# Why form.is_valid() is always false in UserCreationForm, Django

Tags: python, django

I'm making registration in Django. When I access to register/ page, everything shows fine and there isn't any error message. But, the user that I register doesn't save in database in Django (can't find the user on the admin page). Also, the redirect doesn't work.
So, I think '`form.is_valid()` is always false' is the problem.

1. What is the problem?
2. How can I solve this?

This is **view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
  
from .models import *
from django.contrib import messages


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'common/home.html'

class DashboardView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'common/dashboard.html'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')

# class SignUpView(CreateView):
#     form_class = SignUpForm
#     success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
#     template_name = 'common/register.html'


def register(request):
    form = SignUpForm()

    if request.method=='POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            return redirect('login') 

    context = {'form': form}          
    return render(request, 'common/register.html', context)


from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login



def user_login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            return render(request, 'common/login.html', {'error' : 'username or password is incorrect.'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'common/login.html')
```

This is **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your first name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your last name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, required=False, help_text='Enter a valid email address', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your email'}))
    # student_ID = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your student ID'}))
    # CBNU_PW = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your CBNU PW'}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Repeat your password'}))


    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'})
        }
        fields = [
            'username', 
            'first_name', 
            'last_name', 
            'email', 
            # 'student_ID',
            # 'CBNU_PW',
            'password', 
            'password2', 
        ]
```

This is **urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import path
from apps.common.views import DashboardView, user_login, HomeView, register
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('dashboard/', DashboardView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('register/', register, name='register'),
    
    path('login/', user_login, name='login'),

    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(
        next_page='dashboard'
        ),
        name='logout'
    ),
]
```

This is some code  about form in register.html

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="register-form" id="register-form">
                            {%csrf_token%}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
                                {{form.username}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="first_name"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
                                {{form.first_name}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="last_name"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
                                {{form.last_name}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
                                {{form.email}}
                            </div>
                            <!-- <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="student_ID"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
                                {{form.student_ID}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="CBNU_PW"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
                                {{form.CBNU_PW}}
                            </div> -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
                                {{form.password}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password2"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock-outline"></i></label>
                                {{form.password2}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="agree-term" id="agree-term" class="agree-term" />
                                <label for="agree-term" class="label-agree-term"><span><span></span></span>I agree all statements in  <a href="#" class="term-service">Terms of service</a></label>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="form-group form-button">
                                <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" class="form-submit" value="Register"/>
                            </div>
```

Comment: `print(form.errors)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for the help. Where should I write that code?

Comment: in your view below the `if form.is_valid()` clause (so before the `context = {'form': form} `).

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work out. But, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: that is not to *solve* the problem, that is to *diagnose* the problem.

Comment: Oh, I understand the point!

Answer (score 1):

`UserCreationForm` has the fields `password1` and `password2` for the passwords, yet you use `password` and `password2` as your fields. You should simply remove those declarations from your form as you inherit them and also correct it in your template.

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your first name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your last name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, required=False, help_text='Enter a valid email address', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your email'}))
    # student_ID = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your student ID'}))
    # CBNU_PW = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your CBNU PW'}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'})
        }
        fields = [
            'username', 
            'first_name', 
            'last_name', 
            'email', 
            # 'student_ID',
            # 'CBNU_PW',
        ] # declared fields don't need to be added in this list
```

In your template change `{{form.password}}` to `{{ form.password1 }}`